# Get Image from the document using Apache POI

Tags: java, image, apache-poi

I am using Apache Poi to read images from docx.

Here is my code:

```
enter code here

public Image ReadImg(int imageid) throws IOException {
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("import.docx"));
    BufferedImage jpg = null;
    List<XWPFPictureData> pic = doc.getAllPictures();
    XWPFPictureData pict = pic.get(imageid);
    String extract = pict.suggestFileExtension();
    byte[] data = pict.getData();
    //try to read image data using javax.imageio.* (JDK 1.4+)
    jpg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    return jpg;
}
```

It reads images properly but not in order wise.

For example, if document contains

image1.jpeg
image2.jpeg
image3.jpeg
image4.jpeg
image5.jpeg

It reads

image4
image3
image1
image5
image2

Could you please help me to resolve it?

I want to read the images order wise.

Thanks,
Sithik

Comment: what makes you think that it reads images in an unordered way?

Comment: List<XWPFPictureData> pic = doc.getAllPictures(); If I pass imageid=0 then it returns image4.jpeg...Ideally it should return image1.jpeg...Or please suggest me how to acheive this?

Comment: In what basis doc.getAllPictures() retrieve images from the document?

Comment: One solution is to sort the list generated. I believe the method uses an ArrayList so  should maintain insertion order.

Comment: Could you please provide some example how to sort it out when we have 100 images in the document? It will be helpful if you give code example?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void extractImages(XWPFDocument docx) {
    try {

        List<XWPFPictureData> piclist = docx.getAllPictures();
        // traverse through the list and write each image to a file
        Iterator<XWPFPictureData> iterator = piclist.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            XWPFPictureData pic = iterator.next();
            byte[] bytepic = pic.getData();
            BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytepic));
            ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File("D:/imagefromword/" + pic.getFileName()));
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain in a sentence or two how you solved the problem? This would make your answer more useful to future readers and help the OP learn more than just to copy code.