# parsing .docx files to extract text and images

Tags: java

I need to parse a .docx file and extract information , which contains questions in the format of multiple choice questions. It also contains images(such as mathematical equations) , along with text. I tried poi and tika , but only i could extract text. Can any one suggest me if there is any open source java tool for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Image from the document using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897387/get-image-from-the-document-using-apache-poi)

Comment: @MohamedAneesA , this is not about single image , we need to extract both text and image , in to a single file.

Comment: You can check that to extract images. You already are able to extract text as I can infer from your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `.docx` format is essentially a zip. To get to the images, change the `filename.docx` to `filename.zip` and extract the zip.

Comment: i need to extract this data in a sequential form. For example I have a mathematical question , which contains equations as .wmf images , I want to extract the question completely including text and image.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. You can find the the `Relationship Id` in `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` for the files in `word/media` to know where they are referenced within the `word/document.xml`.